# Move specific line from a position to another

Tags: bash, sed, command-line, tail, head

I'm using the ubuntu terminal, I need to move a specific line in a file ( 11th position ) to the first line and then transfer the final result into a new file. The original file contains hundreds of lines.
So far I tried to use the sed command tool, but I'm not achieving what I want. This is what I got so far :

```
[mission 09] $ sed -n -e '1p' -e '11p' bonjour > bonjour2
```

But it only displays the first and 11th line into the new file. But I want the new file to have the revised position wanted with the rest of the original lines.

**Input :**

```
English: Hello 
Turkish: Marhaba 
Italian: Ciao 
German: Hallo 
Spanish: Hola 
Latin: Salve 
Greek: chai-ray 
Welsh: Helo 
Finnish: Hei 
Breton: Demat 
French: Bonjour
```

**Desired output**

```
French: Bonjour 
English: Hello 
Turkish: Marhaba 
Italian: Ciao 
German: Hallo 
Spanish: Hola 
Latin: Salve 
Greek: chai-ray 
Welsh: Helo 
Finnish: Hei 
Breton: Demat
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you need this process to be automatic or is it a one time thing?

Comment: [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/377419/forzatekk) you've asked 4 questions so far but haven't accepted any answers. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n '1h;2,10H;11G;11,$p'
```

First line, copy `h` because of new line, then append `H` until 10.

**At** line 11, get the hold space

**From** 11 to end, print.

---

```
]#  sed -n '1h;2,10H;11G;11,$p' bonj 
French: Bonjour 
English: Hello 
Turkish: Marhaba 
Italian: Ciao 
German: Hallo 
Spanish: Hola 
Latin: Salve 
Greek: chai-ray 
Welsh: Helo 
Finnish: Hei 
Breton: Demat
```

---

This is nicer:

```
]# seq 20 | sed -n '1h;2,10H;11G;11,$p' 
11
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

---

I take your example:

```
]# sed -e 1p -e 11p -n bonj 
English: Hello 
French: Bonjour
```

...with the `-n` switch at the end just to show it counts for both expressions.

I have also `-n`, and then `1h;2,10H`, which should be just `1,10H`, which is a *range* of line numbers and a "hold" (store) command. Nothing gets printed, yet.

`11,$p` is another range. On line 11 it prints what `11G' just got back from hold (ie 1-10) and appended to line 11.

Lines 12 until $ just print themselves, because of `-n`.

---

I should make two `-e` like you:

```
sed -n -e '1h;2,10H' -e '11G;11,$p'
```

From 1,10 is hold, from 11,$ is print.

---

Line 11 has the `G` first, then the `p`. It matters, because:

```
]# seq 20 | sed -n -e '1h;2,10H' -e '11,$p;11G'
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Here line 12 wipes out what line 11 has gotten after printing.

---

**As a function with params**

Always line eleven is boring with a function "putfirst":

```
]# declare -f putfirst 
putfirst () 
{ 
    e="1h;2,$(($1-1))H;${1}G;${1},\$p";
    sed -ne "$e" $2
}
```

Two steps: string generation, then the sed call. "$" has two meanings: "p" is not a variable!

This is the lowest number that works:

```
]# seq 7 | putfirst 3 
3
1
2
4
5
6
7
```

Or with the original "bonj" file:

```
]# putfirst 4 bonj | putfirst 6 |head -4
Latin: Salve 
German: Hallo 
English: Hello 
Turkish: Marhaba
```

This is two seds in a row, but now doing two operations.

---

**Perl**

```
perl -ne '$n++; $h.=$_ if $n<11; print $_.$h if $n==11; print if $n>11' <(seq 20)
```

And as some script, which takes a file name and needs no option:

```
$want=11 ;
while (<>) {
    $n++ ;
    if ($n < $want)            # before $want: store line
        { $lowlines .= $_ ; 
          next }               # next line (avoids 'else')  
    if ($n == $want)           # at line $want: append stored lines to $_    
        { $_ .= $lowlines }   
    print ;                    # print $_ for $n not less than $want
}
```

---

**AWK** (stolen from Ed (not the editor!))

```
NR < 11 { 
    buf[NR] = $0; next 
}
NR >=11 {
    print
    if (NR == 11) {
        for (i=1; i<11; i++) { print buf[i] }
    }
}
```

I used `NR` instead of incrementing `n`, and made the flow more explicit. Same "trick": the `next` simplifies downstream.

---

With `perl -n`

```
$n++ ;
$tmp = $tmp . $_  if $n < 11  ; 
print  $_ . $tmp  if $n == 11 ;
print  $_         if $n > 11  ;
```

This is the best format. Symmetrical.

Answer (score 10):

Using `ed` (the line-editor that `sed` and `grep` are derived from):

```
printf '%s\n' '11m0' 'w bonjour2' 'q' | ed -s bonjour
```

This applies the editing command `11m0` to the file which moves line 11 to before the first line.  It then writes the resulting document to the file `bonjour2` and quits.

Alternatively:

```
printf '%s\n' '11m0' ',p' 'Q' | ed -s bonjour >bonjour2
```

... which instead of writing to a specific file using `ed` commands just prints the whole file to standard output.  The result is then redirected to a new filename.  The `,p` command (short for `1,$p`) will output the whole document to standard output and `Q` will force quit (even though the document has changed).

To make the change in the document in-place (i.e. change the original file), write the result back to the file itself:

```
printf '%s\n' '11m0' 'wq' | ed -s bonjour
```

Example run of one of the above variations:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '11m0' ',p' 'Q' | ed -s bonjour >bonjour2
$ cat bonjour2
French: Bonjour
English: Hello
Turkish: Marhaba
Italian: Ciao
German: Hallo
Spanish: Hola
Latin: Salve
Greek: chai-ray
Welsh: Helo
Finnish: Hei
Breton: Demat
```

To always move the *last* line to the top, use `$m0` in place of `11m0`.  To always move the line that starts with the string `French:`, use `/^French:/m0`.

Comment: what does `printf '%s\n'` do ?

Comment: @ForzaTekk `printf` prints all the arguments from its 2nd argument onward according the the formatting in its first argument.  The format string `%s\n` specifies that each string should be printed as a string (duh) with a newline after it.  The `ed` editor reads editing commands from standard input and expects these to be on separate lines, that's why.  Run the `printf` command by itself (up to, but not including the `|`) to see what gets passed to `ed`.  Also try `printf 'name: %s\n' *` (without the `ed` bit, as an educational exercise).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you just want to move the 11th line to the first line.

So if your original looked like

```
Original line 1
Original line 2
...
Original line 18
Original line 19
Original line 20
```

Then the result would be

```
Original line 11
Original line 1
Original line 2
...
Original line 9
Original line 10
Original line 12
Original line 13
...
Original line 19
Original line 20
```

This can be achieved with *two* passes through the file, but the first pass can be short-cutted so it's not too horrendous

```
( sed -n '11 {p;q}' file ; sed 11d file ) > newfile
```

Basically the first `sed` command only prints line 11 and then quits.  The second `sed` command prints every line *except* line 11.

The result is that, effectively, line 11 is moved to the front of the new file.

Answer (score 2):

After posting my original answer below, I realized now that having an array was overkill and all you really need is:

```
awk '
NR < 11 { buf = buf $0 ORS; next }
{
    print
    printf "%s", buf
    buf = ""
}
' file > new_file
```

e.g.:

```
$ seq 15 | awk '
NR < 11 { buf = buf $0 ORS; next }
{
    print
    printf "%s", buf
    buf = ""
}
'
11
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
12
13
14
15
```

---

Original answer using an array instead of a scalar variable for the buffer:

```
awk '
NR < 11 { buf[++bufSz] = $0; next }
{
    print
    for (i=1; i<=bufSz; i++) {
        print buf[i]
    }
    bufSz = 0
}
' file > new_file
```

e.g.:

```
$ seq 15 | awk '
NR < 11 { buf[++bufSz] = $0; next }
{
    print
    for (i=1; i<=bufSz; i++) {
        print buf[i]
    }
    bufSz = 0
}
'
11
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: I could only use the shell for the moment. I'm learning the basics of computer systems administration.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. awk is a standard UNIX tool that comes on all UNIX boxes, just like sed, grep, ed, and cat. Trying to not use a standard UNIX tool like awk for this and use shell built-ins instead, if that's what you're hoping to do, would be completely inappropriate. An awk solution is no less a "shell" solution than one using sed, or ed or any other non-builtin but standard UNIX tool.

Comment: +1 browsing this on my phone, I originally thought: "no way; this prints 11, 22, 33 etc, out of order !"  Then  I noticed `bufSz = 0`. So it's a bit hacky compared to  Kusalananda's solution, but hey,...  it works... May I suggest you print a few lines of explanation to make your answer more accessible to begineers ? Just saying.

Comment: The main differences between this and the `ed` solution are that the `ed` solution will read the whole input file into memory before working on it while the `awk` solution just stores 11 lines. and the `ed` solution requires a file to work on while the `awk` one can work on a stream, just like `sed` can. I tweaked my answer just now to make it even simpler but honestly I don't think either script need any explanation, it's extremely obvious what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

With `POSIX sed`:

```
$ sed -e '1,11!b' -e '11!H;1h;11!d;G' file
```

Using `perl`:

```
$ perl -lne '
   push(@A,$_),next if $. < 11;
   print for $_, splice @A;
' file
```

Using `bash`:

```
$ (head -n 11 - | tee log | tail -n 1 -; head -n 10 log; cat -;) < file
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler sed than the ones posted (POSIX, no labels):

```
seq 20 | sed '1,10{H;1h;d;};11G'
```

That's: on lines 1 to 10 fill the hold space with those lines (don't print). On line 11, get the hold space back, and let sed do the default from then on: just print each line.
Note that after line 11 the script is a no-op, just leave sed do the default, maybe faster.

In awk:

```
awk 'NR <11{ hold=hold RS $0 }
     NR==11{ print $0, hold  }
     NR >11
    ' file
```

As one liner:

```
$ seq 15 | awk 'NR<11{hold=hold RS $0}NR==11{print $0,hold}NR>11'
11 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
12
13
14
15
```